# How do I fix name-server "mismatched NS record"?

Tags: web-server, domain, nslookup

I am a beginner here, so please be easy on me.

I have bought my domain name from a local registrar of my country(mitsu.in) and bought my domain name www.ashurocks.in from there for about 8 months ago. I also bought the web-hosting from another company (unlimitedgb.com) which gave me a cpanel. (It have linux hosting).

Since I am using the cpanel of unlimitedgb.com, I updated the NS records of my domain name to that of NS records given to me by unlimitedgb. These were-

```
1001.globedns.com.
1002.globedns.com.
```

Now, The website was running fine till today, whene suddenly I got the error `connection timed out` and after some time the error was `server not found at www.ashurocks.in`.

When I used [intoDNS.com](http://www.intodns.com) for **NSLOOKUP**, I got following errors there-

```
Error- Mismatched NS records    WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records.

Error- DNS servers responded    ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
The ones that did not respond are:
72.52.205.202 72.52.205.201

Multiple Nameservers    ERROR: Looks like you have less than 2 nameservers. According to RFC2182 section 5 you must have at least 3 nameservers, and no more than 7. Having 2 nameservers is also ok by me.

Missing nameservers reported by your nameservers    You should already know that your NS records at your nameservers are missing, so here it is again:

1001.globedns.com.
1002.globedns.com. 

SOA record  No valid SOA record came back!
Error- MX Records   Oh well, I did not detect any MX records so you probably don't have any and if you know you should have then they may be missing at your nameservers!
Error- WWW A Record     ERROR: I could not get any A records for www.ashurocks.in!
```

These error suddenly popsup. I haven't changed the configuration of my domain name since I bought it. Till today, the site was working fine and suddenly `server not found` error comes up. I am unable to understand wether the misconfiguration is on my domain name side or on my webserver side(unlimitedgb). Might be there is some possibility that the web-server might be down due to bandwidth.

Please help me soon. I am in middle of this problem right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is quite simple.

**1001.globedns.com** and **1002.globedns.com** are simply not responding to any DNS requests.

```
mypc:~$ dig @1001.globedns.com www.ashurocks.in

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @1001.globedns.com www.ashurocks.in
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

mypc:~$ dig @1002.globedns.com www.ashurocks.in

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @1002.globedns.com www.ashurocks.in
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

It also seems that your former configuration (when having your Name Servers set as mitsu.in) was not the same as what you are trying to accomplish now.

```
mypc:~$ dig @ns1.mitsu.in www.ashurocks.in +answer +nocmd

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @ns1.mitsu.in www.ashurocks.in +answer +nocmd
; (4 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47688
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.ashurocks.in.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ashurocks.in.   28800   IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com.

;; Query time: 638 msec
;; SERVER: 50.23.136.173#53(50.23.136.173)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 16 21
```

Comment: yeah that was it. I asked them(web-server hosting providers) to take a look over the problem and its resolved now. But your feedback made my day :)